# .vimrc file does not apply

Tags: vim

When I start `vim` some of the settings from `.vimrc` file are not applied.
I recognized it e.g. because shortcuts for folding don't work (`za`, `zM`).
I have to run the command

`:source $MYVIMRC`

and this helps but it's uncomfortable to run this command every time I start vim and this was working before without this command.

I'm using Xubuntu 10.04. It's in `~/.vimrc` . Everything works after the `:source $MYVIMRC` command. Maybe it started when I added line to `vimrc` `au! BufWritePost .vimrc source %`

my [.vimrc](http://www.2shared.com/file/L6KiooFJ/vimrc.html)

Some files are applied and some I have to manually apply.

thank you

Comment: +1 for nice title...; now, what is the content of your vimrc? Where is it located and what parts _are_ being loaded ok? Did you check file encoding?

Comment: Does vim throw any errors when it starts? Sometimes if there is a parse error in the file it will abort reading it. Also, are there any conditionals that might abort the other settings?

Comment: sorry @sehe, I edited the title. @xralf, if you *must* source your .vimrc, try nmap <silent> ,sv :so $MYVIMRC to reduce the typing.

Comment: What is the path of your vimrc? What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Xubuntu 10.04. It's in `~/.vimrc` . Everything works after the `:source $MYVIMRC` command. Maybe it started when I added line to `vimrc` `au! BufWritePost .vimrc source %`

Comment: Ok, what is that last line _for_? Does the problem go away when that is removed? I see no other culprits, so you'd actually need to eliminate until you find the problem yourself

Comment: @sehe Yes, it was the culprit, but what's wrong with it

Comment: @pavium, what means your mapping? Has it similar function as `au! BufWritePost .vimrc source %`?

Comment: @xralf, it came from http://www.derekwyatt.org/vim/the-vimrc-file/ and allows you to source the `.vimrc` with a keyboard shortcut. Derek Wyatt is something of a `vim` guru, and worth a look.

Comment: @sehe It wasn't a culprit :-( Some files are applied and some I have to manually apple. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI

I tried with

```
~/Downloads$ cat .vimrc 
se nocompatible
cnoremap QQ echo yup

au! BufWritePost .vimrc source %
```

However, this works like a charm *and* QQ is mapped just like it should. So there will be another culprit involved

```
~/Downloads$ gvim --noplugin -u .vimrc -U .vimrc
```

(this is on Ubuntu 10.10, gvim 7.2) If you really want to debug thins, start gvim with the `-V` flag:

```
gvim -V1
```

or

```
gvim -V10
```

HTH